# Does a single PHP-FPM process correspond to a single PHP process?

Tags: php

I'm trying to better understand how Fast-CGI works. I found this guide helpfull https://help.superhosting.bg/en/cgi-common-gateway-interface-fastcgi.html. But it's still not clear to me. Does a single PHP-FPM child process map to a single PHP process.

Comment: on the stacks i run : **no**.  `php-fpm` usually has a master process with a bunch of worker processes, all controllable with a the config file (see a **[typical configuration file on github](https://gist.github.com/sotarok/2767859)**.

Comment: @YvestLeBorg I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: The subprocesses spawned from the master form a queue/pool. Each of them gets reused for processing scripts. You could say that each FPM child runs one PHP process at maximum at any given time.